# Issues with using free Mercurial hosting like Bitbucket

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket

I'm using Mercurial as my SCM, mainly because I like the ability to commit changes to a project even while offline. I'm going to be moving PCs soon and so I decided to look into finding some free Mercurial repo hosting so I don't lose my data. I signed up for a Bitbucket account and I noticed that they offer space for only a single *private* repository with their free accounts. Wouldn't that mean that some of my stuff might end up publicly available? As in, anyone can download and use it in their projects?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

<strike>Yes, BitBucket only offers one private repository for free.</strike>

**Edit:** See the comments below, BitBucket now offers as many private repos as you want, the restriction on the free plans is a maximum of 5 users accessing these private repos.

---

However, if you're just worried about transferring the projects to your new machine, I think BitBucket is overkill.  Will you be in possession of both machines at once, even for a short period of time?

If so, I would just use [`hg serve`](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/collaborating-with-other-people.html#sec:collab:serve) in each project directory (one at a time) of the old machine and `hg clone http://ip.of.old.machine:8000/ projectname` to clone the changes onto the new machine.

**EDIT:** If you're looking for a way to back up without sharing the repos publicly you could get a [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/) account and clone a copy of each repo to the Dropbox folder on your local machine.  Whenever you push changes they'll get synced up to Dropbox automatically.

If you computer catches on fire and you replace it you just install Dropbox and then clone from the repos in the Dropbox folder to your preferred location.

I'm not sure how well this would work if you want to use the Dropbox copy of the repo on multiple platforms (from a Windows box and a Linux box, for example).

Comment: Well, no, it's not just transferring stuff to the new machine. I'd like to have a 'backup copy' stored somewhere safe in case something disastrous happens to both my PCs. I'm just worried that if I place this on BitBucket as a non-private repo someone will take the code, use it, and then hold me responsible for whatever happens because of it.

Comment: **@cornjuliox** I've edited the answer to mention Dropbox, which might fit your needs.

Comment: I believe they recently started offering unlimited number of private repos for the free 5 user account.

Comment: "BitBucket only offers one private repository for free" - that's now incorrect.  See the Bitbucket site: "All plans include unlimited public and private repositories". The restriction on the free plan is that you have a max of 5 users that have access to private repositories.

Answer (score 9):

run `hg bundle --all` in all your repositories, stuff the bundles somewhere (like a usb stick), `hg unbundle` them on the new machine.

Comment: You don't even have to be that clever. Just zip them up, back up the zips, and unzip. viola!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, unless you put them all under a single repository. Otherwise, you need to pay them for more private repos.

Comment: Yup, how else would they make money from their service? GitHub doesn't even offer a free private repo...

Answer (score 4):

This must have changed since - you can now have unlimited public and private repos :-)

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, **[JavaForge](http://www.javaforge.com) allows hosting private projects**.